# Laravel Relational database language crud

Tags: laravel

i have a 3 tables as i mentioned below,
What I want to do is,
The selection is made with the select option (multi-language) coming from the post. and ids of selected languages ​​available example `1` < arabic
or `1,2` arabic,english
How do I record them? and what relationship do I have to write between my models so that it can render properly.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
Schema::create('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('gallery_language', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignIdFor(Gallery::class)->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignIdFor(Language::class)->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Gallery Model
```

```
public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class);
    }
```

```
GalleryController
```

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Gallery();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->image = 'hello.js';
        $post->save();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Gallery $gallery
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Gallery $gallery)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Gallery $gallery
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Gallery $gallery)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \App\Models\Gallery $gallery
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Gallery $gallery)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Gallery $gallery
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Gallery $gallery)
    {
        //
    }
```

data from post

```
 "title" => "CamScanner12-05-202210"
 "image" => 'image'
 "language" => "1,2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The flow i can tell to you, you can write your code on controller in store or create function. Make sure the relation table was right. Then on field languages can receive array of 1 or more languages.

Comment: what???????????